# Li-ion battery voltage?

Tags: lithium-ion, batteries

My laptop battery is assembled from 4 cells in series. And the voltage of them all is 16.5V, (on battery it writes 14.8V). Can one cell be faulty even then?

Is this a sign that battery is faulty, because if 14.8V DC is declared on packaging, does this mean one of the cells is bad?

Comment: why are you asking?

Comment: @jsotola I want to know does this makes sense and is the battery dead, as I wrote in my edit. How could it be that the battery has bigger voltage than declared from a manufacturer?

Comment: do you measure 16.5V when the laptop is powered up and running on the battery?

Comment: @jsotola It wasn't under load, I used a multimeter to get voltage.

Answer (score 2):

The nominal voltage of lithium ion cells is 3.7V

$$3.7V \cdot 4 = 14.8V$$

but fully charged lithium ion cells actually have 4.1-4.2V open-circuit voltage.

$$4.2V \cdot 4 = 16.8V$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for one or more of the cells to be faulty.

- The internal resistance of a cell can be high.  It would measure
  normal when unloaded, but the voltage would drop drastically when
  under load.
- The capacity of the cell may be reduced to the point where it
  measures ok after charging, but it is unable to supply current for
  very long.